# Unable to convert svg to png properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am trying to save charts designed in d3 as png image. I am using following code to save d3 charts as image-

```
var $container = $('#'+chartId),
content = $container.html().trim();
var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
var w=1366,h=768;
canvas1.id     = "canvas1";
canvas1.width  = w;
canvas1.height = h;
document.getElementById('pngcon').appendChild(canvas1);

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

canvg(canvas, content);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
context.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
var theImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.id="imagepng"
a.download = fileName+".png";
a.href = theImage;
document.body.appendChild(a);
document.getElementById("imagepng").click();
$("#pngcon").html('');

$("#imagepng").remove();
```

My chart looks like this:
[image]

But after downloading it it looks like
 [image]
As you can see axises are not visible and x axis is not showing properly.
I am using following code for horizontal axises

```
make_y_axis = function() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
       .ticks(customTicks)
}
make_x_axis = function() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
         .orient("bottom")
         .ticks(5)
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try setting the styles in Javascript instead of CSS (i.e. using `.style(...)`).

Comment: I assume there's some CSS associated with the SVG, which sets `fill: none` and `stroke: black` for the X axis, and something similar for the Y axis. And, although I've never used `canvg`, I suspect it does not take those CSS rules into account. I'm guessing that any style information you want to capture in canvas should be applied directly on the SVG element, using d3's `.style()` and `.attr()` methods.

Comment: Thank you @LarsKotthoff for you response.definitely will try this in future. I just happened to find an API in js which exports all the css to png images.!!!

Comment: @ValarDohaeris: can you please create the jsfiddle with your complete code?